# Rails: dynamic robots.txt with erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a dynamic text file (robots.txt) in my Rails (3.0.10) app, but it continues to render it as HTML (says the console).

```
match 'robots.txt' => 'sites#robots'
```

Controller:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js, :xml, :css, :txt

  def robots
    @site = Site.find_by_subdomain # blah blah
  end

end
```

app/views/sites/robots.txt.erb:

```
Sitemap: <%= @site.url %>/sitemap.xml
```

But when I visit `http://www.example.com/robots.txt` I get a blank page/source, and the log says:

```
Started GET "/robots.txt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-21 11:22:13 -0500
  Processing by SitesController#robots as HTML
  Site Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `sites`.* FROM `sites` WHERE (`sites`.`subdomain` = 'blah') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 828ms
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I added this to config/initializers/mime_types, cause Rails was complaining about not knowing what the .txt mime type was:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/plain", :txt
```

Note 2: I did remove the stock robots.txt from the public directory.

Comment: Did you remove robots.txt from your public directory?

Comment: Yep, removed the public robots.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that if you define `respond_to` in your controller, you have to use `respond_with` in the action:

```
def robots
  @site = Site.find_by_subdomain # blah blah
  respond_with @site
end
```

Also, try explicitly specifying the `.erb` file to be rendered:

```
def robots
  @site = Site.find_by_subdomain # blah blah
  render 'sites/robots.txt.erb'
  respond_with @site
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  Strangely, if I include both render '...' and respond_with, I get a DoubleRenderError.  But just specifying the full txt.erb path in the render statement, without the respond_with line, seems to work.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 15):

*NOTE: This is a [repost from coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/tlmhnq)*.

Reading up on some [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215132/rails-dynamic-robots-txt-with-erb) to a similar answer on Stackoverflow, I currently use the following solution to render a dynamic robots.txt based on the request's host parameter.

## Routing

```
# config/routes.rb
#
# Dynamic robots.txt
get 'robots.:format' => 'robots#index'
```

## Controller

```
# app/controllers/robots_controller.rb
class RobotsController < ApplicationController
  # No layout
  layout false

  # Render a robots.txt file based on whether the request
  # is performed against a canonical url or not
  # Prevent robots from indexing content served via a CDN twice
  def index
    if canonical_host?
      render 'allow'
    else
      render 'disallow'
    end
  end

  private

  def canonical_host?
    request.host =~ /plugingeek\.com/
  end
end
```

## Views

Based on the `request.host` we render one of two different `.text.erb` view files.

**Allowing robots**

```
# app/views/robots/allow.text.erb # Note the .text extension

# Allow robots to index the entire site except some specified routes
# rendered when site is visited with the default hostname
# http://www.robotstxt.org/

# ALLOW ROBOTS
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

**Banning spiders**

```
# app/views/robots/disallow.text.erb # Note the .text extension

# Disallow robots to index any page on the site
# rendered when robot is visiting the site
# via the Cloudfront CDN URL
# to prevent duplicate indexing
# and search results referencing the Cloudfront URL

# DISALLOW ROBOTS
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

## Specs

Testing the setup with RSpec and Capybara can be done quite easily, too.

```
# spec/features/robots_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Robots" do
  context "canonical host" do
    scenario "allow robots to index the site" do
      Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.plugingeek.com'
      visit '/robots.txt'
      Capybara.app_host = nil

      expect(page).to have_content('# ALLOW ROBOTS')
      expect(page).to have_content('User-agent: *')
      expect(page).to have_content('Disallow:')
      expect(page).to have_no_content('Disallow: /')
    end
  end

  context "non-canonical host" do
    scenario "deny robots to index the site" do
      visit '/robots.txt'

      expect(page).to have_content('# DISALLOW ROBOTS')
      expect(page).to have_content('User-agent: *')
      expect(page).to have_content('Disallow: /')
    end
  end
end

# This would be the resulting docs
# Robots
#   canonical host
#      allow robots to index the site
#   non-canonical host
#      deny robots to index the site
```

As a last step, you might need to **remove the static `public/robots.txt`** in the public folder if it's still present.

I hope you find this useful. Feel free to comment, helping to improve this technique even further.

Comment: Just one changes that I have done on it. Use `render 'allow.text.erb'` instead `render 'allow'` so that `/robots.text and /robots/txt' both work. Also did for `disallow`.

Answer (score 7):

One solution that works in Rails 3.2.3 (not sure about 3.0.10) is as follows:

1) Name your template file `robots.text.erb` # Emphasis on `text` vs. `txt`

2) Setup your route like this: `match '/robots.:format' => 'sites#robots'`

3) Leave your action as is (you can remove the respond_with in the controller)

```
def robots
  @site = Site.find_by_subdomain # blah blah
end
```

This solution also eliminates the need to explicitly specify `txt.erb` in the `render` call mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

For my rails projects I usually have a seperate controller for the robots.txt response

```
class RobotsController < ApplicationController
  layout nil

  def index
    host = request.host
    if host == 'lawc.at' then #liveserver
      render 'allow.txt', :content_type => "text/plain"
    else #testserver
      render 'disallow.txt', :content_type => "text/plain"
    end
  end

end
```

Then I have views named : `disallow.txt.erb` and `allow.txt.erb`

And in my `routes.rb` I have

```
get "robots.txt" => 'robots#index'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea of robots.txt reaching my Web Server.

If you are using Nginx/Apache as your reverse proxy, Static files would be much faster to handle by them than the request reaching rails itself.

This is much cleaner, and I think this is more faster too.

Try using the following setting.

nginx.conf - for production

```
location /robots.txt {
            alias /path-to-your-rails-public-directory/production-robots.txt;
    }
```

nginx.conf - for stage

```
location /robots.txt {
                alias /path-to-your-rails-public-directory/stage-robots.txt;
        }
```

Comment: I generally agree with you. However, the Rails-level solution is needed for anyone using Heroku (which does not, at present, give you access to Nginx settings).

Comment: As I said, this works only if in case if one is using a reverse proxy, in a dedicated remote machine. My idea is that robots.txt should never reach rails, it should be taken care by nginx/apache

Comment: With Heroku now supporting Nginx multi-buildpacks, this should now be supported as long as your project is setup to utilize the Nginx buildpack. I am currently testing an implementation right now.