# How do I disallow index for all sub domains with robots.txt?

Tags: seo

Currently `*.domain.com` shows the same content as `domain.com` and point to the same document root internally,

how can I stop SE from indexing the subdomains ?

Answer (score 1):

How about your subdomains render a different robots.txt file with

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: if this file is only rendered by the subdomains. Your main domain should not render the same robots file

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the goal while using the same robots.txt ?

Comment: i don't think so, robots.txt doesn't allow for full urls, only relative so it doesn't distinguish between domains. There are a few discussions related to dynamic robots.txt, here is something that gives a few examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215132/rails-dynamic-robots-txt-with-erb